# deviceorientation event not called on ios safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

```
<button onclick="test()">click here</button>

<script>
    function test(){
        DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()
                .then(response => {
                    if (response == 'granted') {
                        console.log("granted good");
                        window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', (e) => {
                            // do something with e
                            console.log("device orientation changed ", e);
                        })
                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log("Err ", err);
                })

    }
</script>
```

I have this code. It seems like ios safari asks me for permission which then i grant it. So it logs `granted good` as shown in the `if` statement. The problem is if I change device orientation, event doesn't get called so no logs appear.

Any idea why ? I am using `https:` protocol. So not sure anymore what's going on.

Comment: Are you using the ios simulator of xcode or are you using an apple device to trigger the event?

Comment: ios simulator ? could it be because of that ?

Comment: Probably. You could try a real device if possible or if you just want to trigger the event when the device changes from landscape to portrait mode for example you can use the "orientationchange" event that is working in the simulator for sure.

Comment: orientationchange event is good, but i also need an angle. and I am using window.orientation in the orientationchange event, but window.orientation is deprecated.

Comment: Good. You are just able to use the window.orientation on iOS for now. The newer screen.orientation is not available yet on iOS. To make it more ready for the future (and for other devices) you can just go for a simple `const orientation = screen.orientation || window.orientation` to get the angle.